# Rounding off Input values in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, rounding

I am creating a converter application using Js and its working fine,, I want when the user enters a value with decimal places, it is rounded up by multiplying by 100 whereas if the input has no decimal places the output should remain constant and also slice the final output to a maximum of 4 characters,,,

eg   **60.79(6079) , 876 (876), 009.89(989) , 29.8888 (2988)**

Any assistance will be highly appreciated?

```
document.getElementById('Input').addEventListener('input', converter);

    function converter(e){
        var output = document.getElementById('output');
        var error = document.getElementById('errors');
        var reg= /£?\d+(?:\.\d+)?p?\b/ ;

        var lbs = e.target.value;

        if(reg.test(lbs)){
            error.innerText = "";
            output.style.display = 'block';
            //Convert to sterling pounds
           document.getElementById('sterling').innerHTML = '£' + parseFloat(lbs.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, '')) * 100 ;
          }

        else{
            error.innerText = "Invalid Input";
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- In your regex, replace only the decimal dot (`.`).
- Remove the multiplation by 100.
- Use `slice(0,4)` to make sure only the last 4 chars are included.

and you should be good to go.

Here's a running exmaple:

```js
var lbs = '94.32555£';
var res = '£ ' + parseFloat(lbs.replace(/\./g,'').replace(/\£/g,'').slice(0,4));
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Thanks your code works fine but when the user enters a value with a sterling pound at the beginning £ it displays an error of NaN ,, I wanted the £ to pass through the regex as valid

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach

```
var input = 67.89;
var output = Number((input + "").replace(".", "").slice(0,4));
```

You can then prefix the output by `£` sign

```
output = "£ " + output;
```

Assuming that input is again fetched for conversion, then make it

```
var input = e.target.value;
input = isNaN(input) ? +input.replace(/\£/, "") : +input;
var output = Number((input + "").replace(".", "").slice(0,4));
```

**Demo**

```js
var func = (input) => Number((input + "").replace(".", "").slice(0,4));

console.log( func(60.79) );
console.log( func(876) );
console.log( func(009.89) );
console.log( func(29.8888) );
```

**Note**

- Arithmetic operation is avoided (multiplying a floating point number with `100`) here to avoid the loss of precision

Comment: What of the sterling pound sign £,,, I want it to pass through the regex

Comment: @Pweb Arithmetic on floating point may lead to loss of precision, hence avoided the same. And I don't see the need for regex here.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below :

```
Math.round(29.8888 * 100);
```